# How do I instantiate an EntityManagerFactory that augments a persistence.xml with extra classes?

Tags: java, jpa, derby

I have a module with a persistence.xml for several classes.  I have an application which uses that module, but wants to augment that EntityManagerFactory with a couple of other classes that are specific to this application and don't belong in the module.

If I create a persistence.xml in the application that overrides the persistence unit it does not work reliably (it does work when run from IntelliJ's debugger, but does not work when invoked using a maven appassemble package) because it seems the rules governing which of the persistence.xml files in the various jars takes effect are beyond my understanding, and probably difficult to control.

If I create a second persistence unit to contain only the new tables, then I will need multiple EntityManagerFactory-s to retrieve the various object types in JPA.  I do not currently need to execute queries that join objects from the library module with objects specific to the application module, but I am reasonably certain it would be impossible if the objects were in different persistence units.

Even worse, using multiple persistence units appears to make derby angry because the second persistence unit fails when it finds that the database is already opened (by the first persistence unit; why derby can't share in the same JVM I don't know, and there may be workarounds I do not know).

What are the dangers if you have persistence units that overlap? ( both units have objects mapped to the same table in the same database )

What are the proper guidelines for dealing with persistence units from multiple .jars ?

Answer (score 0):

Using standard JPA functionality, there is no means to supply additional entity classes in runtime.

The approach I recommend is to remove persistence.xml from your modules and create [orm files](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EclipseLink-ORM.XML), which contain the same entities as original persistence.xml files.

Then create single persistence unit in the application and include orm files from all required modules.

This is what has always worked for me an it seems the only reasonable approach with current JPA version.

This way, you end up with single persistence unit, and still having modular and extensible sets of entities.

Comment: It might take me a while to figure out how to implement eclipselink and integrate it with maven.